# need sql query for below data

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @T table (ID int, [Name] varchar(5), [Date] Char(10), Amount int) 
insert into @T(id,  [Name],[Date],Amount) values
(1, 'A4', '01.01.2017', 100 ),
(2, 'B5', '01.01.2017', 80 ),
(3, 'A3', '01.01.2017', 110 ),
(4, 'A4', '01.04.2017', 95 ),
(5, 'A4', '10.10.2017', 105 ),
(6, 'B3', '10.10.2017', 110 ),
(7, 'B3', '15.11.2017', 100 ),
(8, 'B5', '15.11.2017', 95)
```

Need sql query for latest amount for name with respect to date

Comment: I formatted the data in your question to make it easier for others to test against.

Comment: Generally, on questions like this, we're more likely to help someone figure out why their query isn't working, as opposed to simply providing an answer (for fear that we're handing out homework answers, without really helping someone understand the problem and solution. Please show us what you've got so far, query and output. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (modify as needed):

```
Declare @T table (ID int, [Name] varchar(5), [Date] Char(10), Amount int) 
insert into @T(id,  [Name],[Date],Amount) values
(1, 'A4', '01.01.2017', 100 ),
(2, 'B5', '01.01.2017', 80 ),
(3, 'A3', '01.01.2017', 110 ),
(4, 'A4', '01.04.2017', 95 ),
(5, 'A4', '10.10.2017', 105 ),
(6, 'B3', '10.10.2017', 110 ),
(7, 'B3', '15.11.2017', 100 ),
(8, 'B5', '15.11.2017', 95)

;

--Formatting character date to YYYYMMDD
WITH _DataAndDateYYMMDD
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,substring([Date], 7, 4) + substring([Date], 1, 2) + substring([Date], 4, 2) AS DateYYYYMMDD
    FROM @T AS rn
    )
    ,_cte   --Use ROW_NUMBER and PARITION BY NAME ordering by date desc to get max date for each name
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY DateYYYYMMDD DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM _DataAndDateYYMMDD
    )
SELECT *
FROM _cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

```
| ID | Name | Date       | Amount | DateYYYYMMDD | rn |
|----|------|------------|--------|--------------|----|
| 3  | A3   | 01.01.2017 | 110    | 20170101     | 1  |
| 5  | A4   | 10.10.2017 | 105    | 20171010     | 1  |
| 7  | B3   | 15.11.2017 | 100    | 20171511     | 1  |
| 8  | B5   | 15.11.2017 | 95     | 20171511     | 1  |
```